# MySql load data inline adds double quote around string

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, pdo, mysql-error-1064

I am using mysql load data inline to load a csv into the database. I know it's the default behavior to add double quotes around strings but I was hoping there would be an option to turn that off. I tested that if a string contains no space in between i.e car. However if the string is my car it would be shown as "my car". I have tried so many things but can't seem to get rid of these quotes. I added double quotes around all the columns and used Mysql `ESCAPED BY` but that didn't work.

Comment: Please wrote your SQL query. I suggest you to change your CSV when you save him, select different option for the fields separator

Answer (score 0):

I inadvisable you to use excel. Open office Calc is better, cause he can save CSV with more option (and in UTF-8)

Look at my config when I save my CSV before use load data infile (I haven't open office in english, sry).

[image]

And my code for add the CSV in database :

```
$dataload = 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "'.$nomfichier.'"
                        REPLACE
                        INTO TABLE '.$this->csvTable.' CHARACTER SET "utf8"
                        FIELDS TERMINATED BY "\t"
                        IGNORE 1 LINES
                    ';
```

If you can't access to the CSV and save him how you want, you can use the SQL option. [Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) And particulary this lines :

```
   [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work for me in this instance. I tried the LibreOffice route and the text file that I created myself. This is also a new issue, as a previously imported version of the data didn't have that issue. It only seems to appear when there is a double quote character in the field. I'm currently thinking how I can remove it, but it's not elegant.